# Selecting path between two lines using ArcGIS Pro without creating network dataset

Tags: arcgis-pro, select, path, connectivity-analysis

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 without a Network Analyst license so I cannot create a network dataset.

In a feature class of connected lines I would like to be able to select any two of them and find a path of connected lines that goes from one to the other.  I do not need the shortest path because there will only ever be a single path between them.

I use ArcPy to create a test feature class of six single segment lines with a LINE_ID field having values of 1-6.  This is what those lines look like when labeled with their LINE_ID:

[image]

If I have already selected the lines labeled 2 and 5, what I want to do is to obtain a selection/list of the lines making up the path between them, which is the lines labeled 3 and 4.

In the ancient days of ArcInfo Workstation I think ARCEDIT had a command named SELECT PATH which did exactly this on coverage format but I think it used the Node Arc List (NAL) for that.

With some effort I am confident I could write an ArcPy script to get the result I want, by using the matching locations of lines that connect, but is there already a tool which might make getting that selection easy?

The code that created the test feature class in the picture is:

```
import arcpy    
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  
testGDB = (r"C:\Temp\TestProject\TestProject.gdb")
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("GDA2020")
testFCname = "TestLines"
testFC = r"{0}\{1}".format(testGDB,testFCname)
arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(testGDB, testFCname, "POLYLINE", "", "", "", sr)
arcpy.management.DefineProjection(testFC,sr)
arcpy.management.AddField(testFC, "LINE_ID", "LONG", None, None, None,
                          '', "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", '')
testLineListOfLists = [[1,(145,-28),(146,-28)],
                       [2,(146,-28),(146,-27)],
                       [3,(146,-27),(147,-27)],
                       [4,(147,-27),(147,-26)],
                       [5,(147,-26),(148,-26)],
                       [6,(148,-26),(148,-25)]]    
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(testFC,["LINE_ID","SHAPE@"]) as cursor: 
    for line in testLineListOfLists:
        routeID = line[0]
        pointList = arcpy.Array()
        point1xy = line[1]
        point2xy = line[2]
        x = float(point1xy[0])
        y = float(point1xy[1])
        point1 = arcpy.Point(x,y)
        pointList.add(point1)
        x = float(point2xy[0])
        y = float(point2xy[1])
        point2 = arcpy.Point(x,y)
        pointList.add(point2)
        polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
        cursor.insertRow([routeID,polyline])
del cursor
```

It is possible that I am describing an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), so to put the above in context, what I am working towards doing is to use Linear Referencing to take two point events, and then determine any other events that exist along the multiple connecting routes that may exist between them.

Comment: I'm sure you can use networkx if that is an option

Comment: @BERA It's certainly something that I would consider.